# Generate new temporary table from an existing table depending on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops

I am stuck on a query to generate a temporary table having values according to the following condition.

I have a table as follows (Table1)

```
ID
1
5
9
3
10
```

I want a new record set according to the `ID` column value, like if I have `ID=1`, I need 1 row, if `ID=5` I need five rows and so on in the temp table, so the out put table will look something like:

```
ID    Val
1     Null
5     Null
5     Null
5     Null
5     Null
5     Null
```

and so on..

I am using two loops to achieve this, one loop is through `ID` and inner loop through `ID` value, but I believe there must be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @Vikram - hi i have updated my answer just run it again ... i added one more varaiable insertdata which resolve the issue you have with previous query....can just run and infom its working or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a numbers table. Here I use spt_values that has a highest value of 2047. If that is not enough for you you should create a numbers table of your own.

```
declare @T table(ID int)

insert into @T values (1),(5),(9),(3),(10)

select T.ID
from @T as T
  inner join master..spt_values as N
    on N.number between 1 and T.ID
where N.type = 'P'    
order by T.ID
```